# How to correctly require js-cookie with npm and webpack? Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: npm, webpack, laravel-mix, js-cookie

Strange problem but I'm sure it's easily solved. I've tested on a completely empty webpack project.

It says [npm js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) has 0 dependencies so I guess this should work on its own.

```
$ npm install js-cookie --save
```

Then simply ran this in my script file.

```
require('js-cookie');

Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```

The node vendor `js-cookie` 100% exists and no errors on the require.

However just get this error.

[image]

Heres a test project you can download and spin up using `npm install` and then `npm run production` to see error.

http://dev.joshmoto.wtf/npm-webpack-jscookie-project.zip

I'm using laravel mix but I don't see how that can be a the problem?

Comment: const Cookies = require("js-cookie")

Comment: Thank dude this worked but then I had to set `global.Cookies = require('js-cookie');` in order for it to work in my other required js files. But i get the idea now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to assign the required module to a variable in order to use it.

```js
const Cookies = require('js-cookie'); //assign module to variable called "Cookies"
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
console.log(Cookies.get('name'));
```

Read more about this here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Ah great thanks I had to set to `global.Cookies = require('js-cookie');` in order for it to work in my other required js files but I see whats going on now. Cheers for node modules link i'll read up on it.

Comment: You can also require the module (and set it to a const variable) in every file where you need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This also works `import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie';`

Using: `webpack encore` from `Symfony 4/5`

Comment: Nice i'll give it a shot next time. Thanks